# How can I disable CLS compliance checking using C#

Tags: c#, cls-compliant

How do I disable CLS compliance checking?

How can I do it for:

1. The entire assembly
2. A smaller scope, maybe one file or one class...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the CLSCompliant attribute to explicitly mark an assembly or type, e.g.

For an assembly, add the following line in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
```

For a class

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public class Foo
{
}
```

You can also use it for specific type members (methods, properties, etc.) in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`[CLSCompliant(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx) attribute.

Quote from the doc:

> You can apply the
>   CLSCompliantAttribute attribute to the
>   following program elements: assembly,
>   module, class, struct, enum,
>   constructor, method, property, field,
>   event, interface, delegate, parameter,
>   and return value. However, the notion
>   of CLS compliance is only meaningful
>   for assemblies, modules, types, and
>   members of types, not parts of a
>   member signature. Consequently,
>   CLSCompliantAttribute is ignored when
>   applied to parameter or return value
>   program elements.

There's also possibility to [supress compiler warnings](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c17011).